# What is the proper way to add authentication to my django-react blog app

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have my blog app using Django in the backend and React on the front. I want that only an authenticated user can do some actions such as delete and edit articles on the front end. The front end is communicating with the backend via Restful APIs
My project structure at the moment is this

```
base-project
    backend
        blog
        frontend
    manage.py
    db.sqlite3
```

At a later stage, I plan to move the frontend to make it an independent folder.

Do I have to create another Django app to deal with users or there is another way. Please share any reading materials on this that you think can help. The tutorials I see online are either building a blog or a users portal but what is the way to combine the two